# Custom REPL in nodejs

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to play with the nodejs built in REPL from the documentation.

http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

The example of adding an item is as follows:

`repl.start().context.m = msg;`

I cant seem to find away to add multiple menus. I've tried doing:

```
menus = {m = 'hello', f = 'foo'}
repl.start().context = menus
```

But that doesn't work either. I get:

```
testREPL> m
TypeError: needs a 'context' argument.
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:113:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:250:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:199:10)
    at Interface._normalWrite._line_buffer (readline.js:308:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:307:11)
    at Socket.ondata (readline.js:90:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:395:14)
```

Does anybody know how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to the `context` property, you have to add properties to it. What you are trying is "overwriting" it with your own object. Try to assign each property by itself instead:

```
var context = repl.start({}).context;
context.m = 'hello';
context.f = 'foo';
```

Comment: That worked. Im guessing javascript variables become pointers?